# Phone links in Andoid insert wrong country code

Tags: android, html, mobile

So fielded a weird one today - on one of my clients' web site, they say some of their customers using Android phones clicking on a phone link on their website end up with the country code for Nigeria inserted into the number and are directed to an international call. (with the associated charges).

After a previous episode I had made the tel numbers into *explicit links with the USA country code* (+1) included - (number changed below for privacy) but some calls still went to Nigeria.
`<a href="tel://+1701234567" style="color: black;"><strong>703-123-4567</strong></a>`

For the moment, I have removed the anchor tags and attempted to disable phone number detection.
`<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">`

This feels like a weird Android glitch - any insights?
Security issue on Android?

Comment: I tweaked the format to get rid of the "//"  -
 <a href="tel:+12223334455" style="color: black;"><strong>222-333-4455</strong></a> 
format and had the client test it... 

Annnnnddddd...   Client: "Just tried it on Beth’s Samsung and the country code is still for Nigeria—234." The HELL? That's damn weird. So just going to have to disable tel number detection for ALL devices for he time being. 

Actual tech support conversation –
TS Rep:  “It’s not supposed to do that!”
Me: “That’s why we’re having this conversation, son.”

Comment: Follow up - I EXPLICITLY DISABLED Phone format detection, also unlinked or null-linked the #s,  and some android users are still getting sent to Nigeria. 

<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> 

<a href="#" style="color: black;  text-decoration: none;"><strong><span x-ms-format-detection="none">703-785-7187</span></strong></a>

So I am going to have to pop all the strings and replace them with images to display the phone number, WITHOUT linking. 

It's stupid, and clunky, and I shouldn't have to do it, but if it's an Android (or manufacturer-specific) bug - I'm SOL.